# Outputting Error using Try/Catch

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

I'm working on a script which can delete files from an external text file. The script work great but now, I want to improve it by outputting errors to an external text file.

I have tried with try and catch but I don't know why it doesn't work. Here is the relevant ps1 code :

```
$LogFile   = "log.txt" 
$ErrorFile = "error.txt"

Get-ChildItem -Path (Get-Content liste.txt) |
    ft FullName -HideTableHeaders |
    Out-File $logfile -Append

foreach ($i in Get-Content liste.txt) {
    try {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $i -Include *.* -Recurse | Remove-Item
        Write-Output "tout est supprimé"
    } catch {
        Write-Output "Something's wrong" 
    }
}
```

Comment: You are incorrectly using Try/Catch blocks. You should not have code after your catch unless it is in a finally block.

Comment: even if I delete the code after my catch, the script work but only the message for my try appear, even if there is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `-ErrorAction Stop` by the `get-childitem`

Comment: Thank's !! It work perfectly. But now, if I want to catch a non-terminating error like "permission denied" (IOException), it not work and the succes message appear. I know try/catch can't catch non-terminating error but is ther a solution to display an error still?